Generalized complement of a subgroup - does this have a name?
I was messing around with the connection between a subgroup and the set of its cosets, and came up with the concept of a property of a subgroup $S$ of a group $(G, +)$, namely that there exists a different subgroup $T$ of $G$ such that $S \times T$ is isomorphic to $G$.
Doing some research, I found that this concept has a name if $(a, b) \mapsto a + b$ is the isomorphism: then $S$ and $T$ are called complements.
Does this relation have a name if the isomorphism isn't required to be $(a, b) \mapsto a + b$? A kind of generalized complement?
For an example of a generalized complement that isn't a true complement, consider $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$, whose subgroups are all of the form $\{m\mathbb{Z} \ | \ m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ ($0 \in \mathbb{N}$). The trivial subgroups $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ both have complements (namely each other), but no other subgroup does: Let $m \geq 2$ and consider a potential complement $T$ of $S := m\mathbb{Z}$. $T$ must not be $\{0\}$, since otherwise the image of $S \times T$ would consist of only the integers divisible by $m$; so $T$ must contain at least one nonzero integer $k$. But then $T$ also contains $mk$, and then both $(mk, 0)$ and $(0, mk)$ map to $mk$, so the map $(a, b) \mapsto a + b$ from $S \times T$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is not injective. However, the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ do all have generalized complements: whenever $m \neq 0$, $m\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, so in particular $m\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. So every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ other than $\{0\}$ has $\{0\}$ as its generalized complement, and vice versa, $\{0\}$ has every other subgroup as its generalized complements.
Does this have a name? If so, are there more interesting examples (i.e. the generalized complement isn't $\{0\}$?)

You are talking about an isomorphism between $G$ and the "external direct product" of two groups.

The question has been answered in the comment by Arturo.
It seems that your condition is formally that $H$ is a generalized complement of $G$ if there is an isomorphism between $G$ and $H \times H'$ for some group $H'$. In this case, you need to notice that the condition that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ is not used at all, since you do not specify any property of the isomorphism (apparently, you didn't specify that exactly).
So basically we just have two groups $G,H$ in the abstract sense and ask if $H$ is a direct factor of $G$. In your example, $G$ was indecompsable, so this notion was not very interesting.
